# R package ff with cross products of a number of different keys fails

Tags: r, ffbase

I am coming across difficulties using the ff package, when attempting to create cross-products of a number of different keys. Using expand.ffgrid(), there are no issues when passing individual ff objects as below:

`test_ff <- expand.ffgrid(a=ff(c(0,1,2)), b=ff(c(0,1))) #-- Runs fine`

However, to productionise this for an environment where I don’t know the number of ff objects I’m passing in, I’d like to pass in those objects as a list, as shown below

`test_ff <- expand.ffgrid(list(a=ff(c(0,1,2)), b=ff(c(0,1)))) #-- This fails`

The documentation implies (not very clearly) that this should be possible, and this syntax works fine using expand.grid(). Is this functionality that is not yet implemented in ff or am I missing something?

My original problem is to create a full outer join over a number of dataframes – this not being easy (or possible?) in ff really is causing me a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently lists are not implemented but why not use do.call in that case?
As in

```
require(ffbase)
x <- list(a=ff(c(0,1,2)), b=ff(c(0,1)))
test_ff <- do.call(expand.ffgrid, x)
```

I'll add the feature request on github